# Parse JSON Results into Multiple HTML columns Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working with an API and would like to extract API Results into an HTML table columns with X number of rows. This an issue with JQuery looping, do not know how to do it. Thanks in Advance!

```
/////JSON SAMPLE/////
{
  "123SC": [{
      "name": "First",
      "Custnumber": "123SC"
    },
    {
      "name": "Fourth",
      "Custnumber": "123SC"
    }
  ],
  "67BC": [{
    "name": "Second",
    "Custnumber": "67BC"
  }],
  "99ABC": [{
    "name": "Third",
    "Custnumber": "99ABC"
  }]
}
///////// END JSON //////
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Forth</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123SC</td>
    <td>123SC</td>
    <td>67BC</td>
    <td>99ABC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need nested loops for the keys of the main object and then the arrays in each property. You'll need to do this twice. First for the headings row where you print the value of the `name` properties. Second for the row that contains the top-level keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    let json = {
        "123SC": [{
            "name": "First",
            "Custnumber": "123SC"
        },
        {
            "name": "Fourth",
            "Custnumber": "123SC"
        }
        ],
        "67BC": [{
            "name": "Second",
            "Custnumber": "67BC"
        }],
        "99ABC": [{
            "name": "Third",
            "Custnumber": "99ABC"
        }]
    };

    let arrays = [];
    for (const i in json) arrays = [...arrays, ...json[i]];



    let names = '<tr>';
    let Custnumber = '<tr>';
    for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        names += `<td>${arrays[i].name}</td>`;
        Custnumber += `<td>${arrays[i].Custnumber}</td>`;
    }
    names += '</tr>';
    Custnumber += '</tr>';
    let html = `<table style="width:100%" border="2">${names + Custnumber}</table>`;
    document.write(html);
```